# Do I have the right to the bundle that generate by / dependent on open-source libraries?

Tags: commercial, distribution, closed-source

I created a project with the following structure:

[image: license]

**The question is:**

1. Do I have the right to the **BUNDLE** where I do not want clients to resell the **BUNDLE** they have bought?
2. Is it sufficient to include the **license of the modules / libraries** in a file such as thirdPartiesNotices.txt as [VS Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/ThirdPartyNotices.txt) does?

Comment: So what does the license text tell you? Have you read it? Your question shows no reflection of that at all. What makes you think you may, what makes you doubt it?

Comment: Thanks for the respon @planetmaker! I still confused about the concept of licensing. Almost libraries that I'm use is under MIT licenses. MIT: if I use the code, I must place  the license on my project. So, indirectly, will my BUNDLE be MIT licensed (so that my clients can resell the BUNDLE) ?

Comment: A license is a simple concept: it tells you on which conditions you may use and distribute the piece of software. In your case: the MIT license doesn't say what you quote. (A license is not a copyright notice and vice versa)

Comment: Yet with FLOSS licenses you nearly never make anything wrong, if you use the same license as the projects you use(d)

Comment: What license for BUNDLE fits these conditions: only clients with direct permission from me can use BUNDLE, and also prevent it from reselling / redistributing it? @planetmaker

Comment: No open-source license as that is one of the fundamental freedoms: the right to modify and distribute and exploit commercially freely as long as the license conditions are met.

Comment: So, can I make the BUNDLE as closed-source but still use the open-source libraries? @planetmaker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Do I have the right to the BUNDLE where I do not want clients to resell the BUNDLE they have bought?

Yes, you have that right, but you will need to get a lawyer to draft a closed-source license for you. The restriction to disallow reselling is not something that an open-source license can offer.

The MIT license of the libraries you use is compatible with closed-source licenses, so that isn't a hindrance.

> 2. Is it sufficient to include the license of the modules / libraries in a file such as thirdPartiesNotices.txt as VS Code does?

Yes, that is sufficient.